# What are the guidelines for using UIDatePickers on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipickerview, uidatepicker, picker

I know that it is against Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines to have a picker view extend all the way across the screen on an iPad so that it is touching both sides. Is this the same case for date pickers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err, yea, seeing as they are basically the same thing. Remember though the HIG is not a set of rules, they are **guidelines**. If you think a full-width picker makes sense for your app do it.

IMO, I cannot think of a reason to use a full-width picker on iPad. It would look quite ugly. Your better off showing the UIDatePicker in a popover. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's fine, I got an answer somewhere else, so thanks for your help. I remember about a year ago they REJECTED my app because it had a full length picker, from side to side. And I was extremely confused because in the XIB file, when you drag a picker view to the view, IT AUTOMATICALLY resizes to the entire width. That's a bug in Apple's program that's encouraging you to break the guidelines!

Answer (score 2):

An excerpt from the iOS Human Interface Guidelines:

> On iPad, present a date and time picker only within a popover. A date
>   and time picker is not suitable for the main screen.

Also:

> The overall size of a date and time picker is fixed at the same size
>   as the iPhone keyboard.